# Django CreateView inline formset instance and queryset

Tags: django

So I have a view to make customer payments. When the page is first rendered there's an empty form. I'm using ajax to choose a customer then return an html string of all the outstanding invoices for that customer and inserting it into the empty form.

When the form is submitted in order for the outstanding invoices formset to be valid I need to pass it the matching instance and queryset as the ajax generated formset. The problem I'm running into is passing the customer instance into get_context_data().

Right now I have customer hard-coded to pk=1 and can confirm that the formset is valid. There's also a hidden field with the value for customer in the form but I'm not sure how to pass that into get_context_data().

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

```
class PaymentCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'payment_create.html'
    model = Pay_hdr
    success_url = reverse_lazy('payments')
    form_class = PaymentHeadForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PaymentCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['customers'] = Customer.objects.all().order_by('name')
        if self.request.POST:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)  # need to replace this line
            queryset = Accounts_receivable.objects.filter(customer=customer).exclude(balance=0).order_by('-date_trans')
            context['user'] = self.request.user
            context['formset'] = ARLineFormset(self.request.POST, instance=customer, queryset=queryset)
        else:
            context['formset'] = ARLineFormset()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        user = context['user']
        formset = context['formset']
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            head = form.save(commit=False)
            invoices = formset.save(commit=False)
            head.created_by = user
            head.save()
            for invoice in invoices:
                if invoice.temp_amount > 0:
                    invoice.process_payment(head, invoice.temp_amount, user)
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return render(self.request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data(form=form))

def ajax_payment_choose_customer(request):
    customer_id = request.GET.get('customer_id', None)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)
    outstanding = Accounts_receivable.objects.filter(customer=customer).exclude(balance=0).order_by('-date_trans')
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = PaymentHeadForm()
        formset = ARLineFormset(instance=customer, queryset=outstanding)
        context = {
            'customer': customer,
            'form': form,
            'outstanding': outstanding,
            'formset': formset
        }
        html = render_to_string('payment_insert_forms.html', context)
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)`

with `customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=self.request.POST.get('customer'))`